# File Compressor In Assembly

Tags: compression, x86

In an effort to get better at programming assembly, and as an academic exercise, I would like to write a non-trivial program in x86 assembly.  Since file compression has always been kind of an interest to me, I would like to write something like the `zip` utility in assembly.

I'm not exactly out of my element here, having written a simple web server using assembly and coded for embedded devices, and I've read some of the material for zlib (and others) and played with its C implementation.

My problem is finding a routine that is simple enough to port to assembly.  Many of the utilities I've inspected thus far are full of `#define`'s and other included code.  Since this is really just for me to play with, I'm not really interested in super-awesome compression ratios or anything like that.  I'm basically just looking for the RC4 of compression algorithms.

Is a Huffman Coding the path I should be looking down or does anyone have another suggestion?

Comment: For the record, the "RC4 of compression algorithms" (short code, easy to implement) is probably LZ4 (http://code.google.com/p/lz4/)

Comment: @mihi We have very different definitions of "easy to implement".  RC4 is literally a couple of loops.  Looking at the LZ4 implementing you link for less than 2 minutes, it did not immediately stand out to me how to implement it.

Comment: Due to Google Code dying, the link does no longer contain the same text as it did in 2013. :(

The "most similar" page I found to that short introduction to LZ4 is http://lz4.github.io/lz4/lz4_Block_format.html - but I only skimmed it and not sure whether that is easy enough

But anyway, I don't know of any compression algorithm easier one to implement (for decompression):  one loop with 2 loops inside, and a total of 8 branch labels in my x86 asm implementation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And here is a more sophisticated algorithm which should not be too hard to implement: [LZ77 (containing assembly examples)](http://www.arturocampos.com/ac_lz77.html) or [LZ77 (this site contains many different compression algorithms)](http://michael.dipperstein.com/lzss/index.html).

Comment: This was fantastic, and eventually what I ended up doing.  Thanks so much!

Comment: Current state of the art is zstd for a good general-purpose tradeoff of speed vs. compression ratio. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zstandard). Faster than gzip/deflate, and generally as good or better compression.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to write a decompressor for [DEFLATE](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1951.html) (the algorithm behind zip and gzip). zlib's implementation is going to be heavily optimized, but the RFC gives pseudocode for a decoder. After you have learned the compressed format, you can move on to writing a compressor based on it.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  The heavily optimized code was exactly what I was trying to avoid reading, but the RFC was relatively painless to follow.

Answer (score 1):

I remember a project from second year computing science that was something similar to this (in C).

Basically, compressing involves replacing a string of `xxxxx` (5 x's) with `@\005x` (the at sign, a byte with a value of 5, followed by the repeated byte. This algorithm is very simple. It doesn't work that well for English text, but works surprisingly well for bitmap images.

Edit: what I am describing is [run length encoding](http://www.data-compression.info/Algorithms/RLE/index.htm).

Comment: Thank you, while I didn't select this method, the background reading was very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [UPX](http://upx.sourceforge.net/) executable packer. It contains some low-level decompressing code as part of unpacking procedures...

Comment: Delicious.  <3 the UPX source.